# Show issue on React-admin, row is unclickable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

Hello i'm hiring for a solution my show doesn't work on the row of my table. The cursor doesn't change to let me click on a row and even if i click nothing happened. That's my code

```
//in App.tsx
<Admin dataProvider={DataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
    <Resource name="users" list={UsersList} show={UserShow}/>
  </Admin>
```

```
// in users.tsx
export const UsersList = () => {
  // const isSmall = useMediaQuery((theme : any) => theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
  return (
    <List filters={userFilters}>
        <Datagrid>
          <TextField source="id" />
          <TextField source="firstname" />
          <TextField source="lastname" />
          <EmailField source="email" />
          <TextField source="phone" />
          <TextField source="candidatureStatus"  />
          <TextField source="created_at" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
export const UserShow = () => (
  <Show>
    <SimpleShowLayout>
      <TextField label="test" source="email" />
      <TextField source="firstname" />
      <TextField source="lastname" />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
  )
```

Even if i followed the tutorial on react admin i can't display a showScreen

Comment: nothing happens when you click on the Show button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the Show form when clicking on a row in the List, you need to add:

```
<Datagrid rowClick="show">
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#rowclick